# Events are not getting fired in selenium, need resolution

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, onblur, onfocus

I have three text fields and submit button on a browser page..

Lets say A, B, C, and submit 
(All fields are optional)

If I enter a value manually in field A. Then Field B and Field C gets disabled and if i enter in either B or C, Field A get disabled. 
Click on Search button, No Error displayed.

But doing the same thing with Selenium automation in C# language, i.e. Entering a value in A, Other two fields are not getting disabled and trowing error after clicking on Submit button, saying Enter a value for B, Enter a Value for C.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Consider reading this article on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to create a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You probably need to move the cursor out of the initial field to trigger the update action. Have you tried clicking into a different field, e.g. enter value into field A, click into field B?

Comment: Yes, I have tried all the possible ways like trigger Change, OnChange everything

Comment: Actually, Field A, B, C are numeric text boxes and they does not support sendkeys, hence i have applied java script to enter values in those fields. so the values are updated on ui but events are not getting fired.

Comment: What do you mean by `numeric text boxes and they does not support sendkeys`? As per my understanding sendkeys should work on input type text. Did you figured out what is the associated event?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO. You can trigger the `change` event after entering the value in the `eleInputboxA`

```
IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
js.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].dispatchEvent(new Event('change', {'bubbles': true,'cancelable': true}));",eleInputboxA);
```

*Change the event name based on the associated event.

Answer (score 0):

What supputuri said should work. Although I think the following will be a bit more concise.

My recommendation would be this:

```
     using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.Extensions;   

     driver.ExecuteJavascript("$('#TextBoxId01').val('New Text Value').trigger('change').trigger('mouseup')");
```

This will combine the text entry and trigger event all in one. Since we are triggering the event via javascript, it doesn't make much sense to do the text input with Selenium anyway. Selenium, in this case, is failing to mimic a real user's input already, so no extra losses by doing this.

Note, that I added both "change" and "mouseup" event triggers. I can't tell which one yours is using. Remove whichever is unnecessary. Although if you examine the element and see that it should trigger several events, chain all events you would need to trigger as I do above.

You can query the DOM for events via:

```
   getEventListeners($("#SomeElement")[0]); //Javascript
   $._data($("#SomeElement")[0], "events"); //JQuery
```

Comment: I will try first one, but when i am applying this to field A, this will impact on other fields B and C automatically or not. Because i want to simulate the manual action using selenium